# javascript: get value from json

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to get value from the json obtained by this Yahoo web service: http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo

This is the data obtained from this url:

```
{
  "geonames": [
    {
      "fcodeName": "capital of a political entity",
      "toponymName": "Mexico City",
      "countrycode": "MX",
      "fcl": "P",
      "fclName": "city, village,...",
      "name": "Mexiko-Stadt",
      "wikipedia": "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexico_City",
      "lng": -99.12766456604,
      "fcode": "PPLC",
      "geonameId": 3530597,
      "lat": 19.428472427036,
      "population": 12294193
    },
    {
      "fcodeName": "capital of a political entity",
      "toponymName": "Manila",
      "countrycode": "PH",
      "fcl": "P",
      "fclName": "city, village,...",
      "name": "Manila",
      "wikipedia": "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manila",
      "lng": 120.9822,
      "fcode": "PPLC",
      "geonameId": 1701668,
      "lat": 14.6042,
      "population": 10444527
    },
    {
      "fcodeName": "capital of a political entity",
      "toponymName": "Dhaka",
      "countrycode": "BD",
      "fcl": "P",
      "fclName": "city, village,...",
      "name": "Dhaka",
      "wikipedia": "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhaka",
      "lng": 90.40743827819824,
      "fcode": "PPLC",
      "geonameId": 1185241,
      "lat": 23.710395616597037,
      "population": 10356500
    },
    {
      "fcodeName": "capital of a political entity",
      "toponymName": "Seoul",
      "countrycode": "KR",
      "fcl": "P",
      "fclName": "city, village,...",
      "name": "Seoul",
      "wikipedia": "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seoul",
      "lng": 126.977834701538,
      "fcode": "PPLC",
      "geonameId": 1835848,
      "lat": 37.5682561388953,
      "population": 10349312
    },
    {
      "fcodeName": "capital of a political entity",
      "toponymName": "Jakarta",
      "countrycode": "ID",
      "fcl": "P",
      "fclName": "city, village,...",
      "name": "Jakarta",
      "wikipedia": "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta",
      "lng": 106.84513092041016,
      "fcode": "PPLC",
      "geonameId": 1642911,
      "lat": -6.214623197035775,
      "population": 8540121
    },
    {
      "fcodeName": "capital of a political entity",
      "toponymName": "Tokyo",
      "countrycode": "JP",
      "fcl": "P",
      "fclName": "city, village,...",
      "name": "Tokio",
      "wikipedia": "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo",
      "lng": 139.69171,
      "fcode": "PPLC",
      "geonameId": 1850147,
      "lat": 35.6895,
      "population": 8336599
    },
    {
      "fcodeName": "capital of a political entity",
      "toponymName": "Taipei",
      "countrycode": "TW",
      "fcl": "P",
      "fclName": "city, village,...",
      "name": "Taipeh",
      "wikipedia": "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taipei_Railway_Station",
      "lng": 121.531846,
      "fcode": "PPLC",
      "geonameId": 1668341,
      "lat": 25.047763,
      "population": 7871900
    },
    {
      "fcodeName": "capital of a political entity",
      "toponymName": "Bogotá",
      "countrycode": "CO",
      "fcl": "P",
      "fclName": "city, village,...",
      "name": "Bogotá",
      "wikipedia": "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogot%C3%A1",
      "lng": -74.08175468444824,
      "fcode": "PPLC",
      "geonameId": 3688689,
      "lat": 4.609705849789108,
      "population": 7674366
    },
    {
      "fcodeName": "capital of a political entity",
      "toponymName": "Beijing",
      "countrycode": "CN",
      "fcl": "P",
      "fclName": "city, village,...",
      "name": "Peking",
      "wikipedia": "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beijing",
      "lng": 116.397228240967,
      "fcode": "PPLC",
      "geonameId": 1816670,
      "lat": 39.9074977414405,
      "population": 7480601
    },
    {
      "fcodeName": "capital of a political entity",
      "toponymName": "Hong Kong",
      "countrycode": "HK",
      "fcl": "P",
      "fclName": "city, village,...",
      "name": "Hong Kong",
      "wikipedia": "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong",
      "lng": 114.157691001892,
      "fcode": "PPLC",
      "geonameId": 1819729,
      "lat": 22.2855225817732,
      "population": 7012738
    }
  ]
}
```

How get `fcodeName` from this json ?

I know this is a very simple for you all, but i am working for the first time with html, javascript and jquery. I googled it but not able to get how to work with json data. I am expecting a detailed explanation. Thank you devs...

**Edit:**

I tried this way:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var url = "http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            console.log("Success: "+data.geonames[0].fcodeName);
        },
        error:function(data){
            console.log("Error: "+data);
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is the console log i get (I am using Netbeans IDE):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined (12:02:53:552 | error, javascript)
    at $.ajax.success (public_html/index.html:23:52)
    at c (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4:26036)
    at p.fireWith (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4:26840)
    at k (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6:14258)
    at r (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6:18646)
```

Comment: Did you not check how to do this at all?

Comment: Your code should work right with the response example you provided. However, the URL you are provided in your AJAX call is returning `{"status":{"message":"the daily limit of 30000 credits for demo has been exceeded. Please use an application specific account. Do not use the demo account for your application.","value":18}}` here. Maybe that's why it is not working. Have you checked your console for errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*How get fcodeName from this json ?*

You can use

```
  data.geonames[0].fcodeName
```

As `geonames` is an array you have to iterate using index

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qnvRL/)

Comment: Whats wrong with the above code. Check my edit.

Comment: @shree202, nothing is wrong with your code. You can `console.log(data)`. currently `geonames` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You use JSON.parse() to turn this into a data structure, then you just pull it out of the data.